# why inverse trigonometric function DNE

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inverse

Determine the exact value

$\arccos\left[\sec\left(\dfrac{7\pi}{6}\right)\right]$ and $\text{arcsec}\left[\sin\left(\dfrac{13\pi}{6}\right)\right]$

Why does the exact value of these two questions not exist?

Comment: What number do you get inside the brackets of the two inverse functions? Start with that and then have a think about what an inverse function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just working with the first one.

$\sec(7\pi/6)
=\frac1{\cos(7\pi/6)}
=-\frac{2}{\sqrt(3)}
< -1
$
so
$\cos(\sec(7\pi/6))
$
does not exist
(unless you go into the
complex domain).

In general,
since
$-1 \le \cos(x) \le 1$,
we have
$\sec(x) \ge 1$
or
$\sec(x) \le -1$.

The only times when
$\arccos(\sec(x))
$
exists in the reals
are when
$\sec(x)
=\pm 1
$,
or
$x = n\pi
$.